# Comment exprimer la phrase russe "Хорошего понемножку" ?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique, russe

Comment traduit-on du russe le syntagme "Хорошего понемножку"?

La phrase mot-à-mot traduite comme "*du bon par petite quantité*" en gros veut dire que "ça suffit!... car on doit avoir une *mesure* pour les *bonnes choses*"...

Les variantes en anglais par exemple seraient parmi:

- *Enough's enough*
- *Better a little fire to warm us, than a great one to burn us.*
- *Too much of a good thing is good for nothing.*
- *Too much water drowned the miller.*

En russe c'est utilisé pour refuser poliment un interlocuteur... genre "*ça m'aurait fait vraiment plaisir, mais je me force de m’abstenir quand même*".

> ОН  : — Хочешь еще погуляем ?
>   ОНА : — *Хорошего понемножку*, давай завтра !
>
> Lui  : — On se promène encore un peu ?
>   Elle : — *Ça suffit*, venez demain !

Answer (score 5):

Du point de vue philosophique

> *Rien de trop*

était gravé sur le temple de Delphes.

Il existe des proverbes pour les excès de toutes sortes :

> *Qui trop embrasse mal étreint* ou *Avoir les yeux plus gros que le ventre*, se faire trop d'illusions
>
> *Pas plus haut que le verre*, familier et bistrotier.
>
> *Entre trop et trop peu est la juste mesure* - Gilles de Noyers
>
> *Trop de possession, comme trop de passé, finissent par alourdir* - Michel Chevrier
>
> *Trop tendue la corde casse*, proverbe.
>
> *Qui trop embrasse mal étreint* de Albertano de Brescia, entré dans les proverbes.
>
> *Trop boire noie la mémoire*, proverbe français... au pays du vin !

Pour justifier un refus : quand cela gène d'avoir plus, car ce n'est pas justifié ou que cela devient encombrant.

> *Trop c'est trop* : Enough's enough.
>
> *Point trop n'en faut*.

Pour dire que cela suffit, et que de toute façon l'excès va poser problème :

> *La coupe est pleine*.

Pour arrêter une activité, une conversation, un échange :

> *C'est suffisant* ou *Cela suffit*.
>
> J'arrête, *je n'en peux plus* (ou "Arrête ! *je n'en peux plus*")

---

***P.S.*** suite au commentaire :

> Il ne faut pas abuser des bonnes choses.

... formule élégante qui remercie en même temps de la qualité de ce qui est offert.

> Point trop n'en faut.

... pour être le chantre du juste milieu et clore une discussion apaisée où tout le monde est d'accord sur la conclusion énoncée.

Comment: merci! j'ai rajouté un exemple de dialogue...

Comment: @Serge -- Du russe, je n'en connais que l'intonation française émigrée dans le parler d'une amie... de bon moments, dont je ne ma lasse pas, contrairement à votre interrogation :)

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax -- Je vais intégrer votre commentaire dans ma réponse, car beaucoup s'épargnent la lecture des commentaires -- Rien ne dit que A.Froissard n'a pas repris un proverbe de sagesse paysanne traditionnelle, de maître artisan en son métier, de bedaud gourmand qui se modère... Je penche pour l'anonymat de https://www.citation-ou-proverbe.fr/anonyme/86159-abuser

Comment: ah, le *PS* est beaucoup plus proche de ce que je cherche ! ;)

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax -- J'avais pensé à https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hapax et à https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28informatique%29 ... forme de Janus dont la maîtrise des langues décape les neurones ...

Answer (score 0):

Pour justifier poliment un refus en indiquant que ce n'est pas l'action qui rebute mais la quantité excessive, on peut également dire:

> Non merci: l'excès nuit en tout ! Reprenons demain.

Les formules ci-dessous sont plus catégoriques, plus sèches (si la personne insiste...) car elles sont également utilisées lorsqu'une limite a déjà été dépassée.

> Trop c'est trop
>
> ça suffit comme ça

Comment: humm... pas sûr que *l’excès nuit en tout* indique que c'est agréable...

Comment: La suggestion de @comethapaxd'ajax est, il est vrai. "L'excès nuit en tout " est un fait indiscutable. L'idée est que même les meilleures choses deviennent nocives si l'on en abuse (cela véhicule donc la même idée que "comet" même si le "tout" est plus général que le "bonnes choses"). J'ai modifié ma réponse pour mieux expliciter ma compréhension de la phrase

Comment: dans le commentaire précédent, je voulais écrire: "sa suggestion est, il est vrai, meilleure".